# Box2d Collision issue

Tags: java, box2d, collision

I'm creating a physics game and in my game there are many kinds of balls.
now, there's a special ball that suppose to pass through walls, but other balls
can collide with it (so only walls wouldn't "feel" the special ball).

I didn't figure how to id exactly.
what is the best practice?

thanks,
sock.socket

Comment: Does it work if it has `0` density?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put an extra condition on the ball-to-wall collision checking logic to only check/allow bouncing if the ball is not of the special type